# nalgebra apply function to every element of a vector

Tags: rust, nalgebra

sorry if this is a noob question but is it posible to apply a function to every element in a nalgebra vector?

if I for example have a vector like this:

```
type Vector2x1 = SVector<f32, 2>;
let vector = Vector2x1::new(2.0, 2.0);
```

how can I apply a function which takes a f32 as an argument to every element in the vector?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for what you're looking for? There's a section "Iteration, map, and fold" on this page: https://docs.rs/nalgebra/latest/nalgebra/base/struct.Matrix.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-stating @AlphaModder's comment, you can use the function `map` to do this. Alternativaley you could iterate over the elements and map each one, but `.map(x)` conveniently handles the other steps for you without the overhead (if any) of an iterator (Ex: `.into_iter().map(x).collect::<Self>()`).

```rust
// Create a new Vector2<f32> (Same thing as SVector<f32, 2>)
let vector: Vector2<f32> = Vector2::new(1.0, 2.0);

// Use .map to apply a closure to each element
let result = vector.map(|x: f32| x * 2.0);

// Do something with the result
assert_eq!(result, Vector2::new(2.0, 4.0));
```

If you did not already know, you can also use a function in place of the closure.

```rust
fn foo(x: f32) -> f32 {
    x + 1.0
}

let result = vector.map(foo);
```

This approach will work for any variant of `Vector` or `Matrix` (`impl<T, R: Dim, C: Dim, S: RawStorage<T, R, C>> Matrix<T, R, C, S>`).